# How can I use #checked to show/hide menu in responsive mode?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a responsive menu navbar and according to some sites, I tried using the checkbox. Unfortunately, I am unable to make it operational due to reasons unbeknown to me (it would be an overestimate to say I'm an amateur at this). When checking/unchecking the button nothing happens. If there is another more effective way of doing this please do share.
I mustn't use anything but HTML and CSS to make it.
Here's the code. (I know I shouldn't post the entirety of it but I'm too inexperienced to know what's of value and what's not - so sorry about that!)

html:

```
<nav>
        <!--logo-->
        <a href="#" class="logo">TBD</a>
        <!--meni-->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Landing page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </label>
</nav>
```

css:

```
    nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 0px 5%;
}

nav ul li{
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;

}

nav ul li a{
    margin: 30px;
    font-family: calibri;
    color: #505050;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.checkbtn{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#check{
  display: none;
}
```

...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 796px) {

    .checkbtn{
    display: block;
    margin-right: 40px;
    color: black;
    }
nav ul {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: #ebeef4;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 1;
        display: none;
    }

    nav ul li {
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
    }

    nav ul li a{
        font-family: calibri;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #5c5c5c;
    }

    nav ul li a:hover{
        color: #121212;
    }

    #check:checked ~ ul{
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

    }

    nav.active ul {
        display: flex !important;
    }
```

I'm really trying to comprehend this and once again I am so sorry for the long post. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check boxes are inputs that need to run by form. What you want to happen when it’s checked?

Comment: the checkbox represents (or at least it should) a button which through an icon shows/hides the menu/navbar when at smaller resolution... if that makes sense :/

Comment: Best way is to make button, hide in css then display as smaller resolution. Make JavaScript that will open navigation once the button will be pressed. Another option to use bootstrap which will give you it already (all in documentation of bootstrap)

Comment: yes, except I can't use bootstrap... nor javascripit... nvm, thanks anyway